# Updating node and npm using Homebrew

Tags: node.js, homebrew

I want to upgrade npm but I need Node version >0.10.32

Typing `$ brew upgrade node` I get:

> Error: node 7.2.1 already installed

but with `$ node -v` I get:

> v0.10.24

Why are there two version formats and how can I get node updated to the required version?

I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different versions of Node installed in different paths.

The one in the directory closer to the front of your `$PATH` environment variable is 0.10.24.

The one installed by brew is 7.2.1.

If you want to use the brew managed one, then the easiest thing to do is to uninstall the other version.

Alternatively, use [the full path to the brew managed one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/145437/where-can-i-find-the-installed-package-path-via-brew).

Comment: Right. So why the different versions and if I need >0.10.32 how do I know if the one in the different format meets this requirement?

Comment: (a) Because someone installed two different versions (b) Because the error message you quoted from brew says it does

Comment: I mean why the two different version formats? Is 7.2.1 > 0.10.32 as they seem totally out of sync?

Comment: The version formats are the same. http://semver.org/ One is just much newer than the other.

Comment: Thanks. So what's the best way to remove the old version of Node?

Comment: Depends how it was installed in the first place. Use an uninstalled if you can. Failing that, just delete its files